# How to make expandable boxes when hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am currently trying to make a few divs or boxes open and animate downward when hovered over. I went onto bootstrap docs and see no way to do it on their docs. I was thinking maybe using JS to do the job, but i dont have much knowledge regarding JS, and i went online to see if i could find some clues n what kind of JS i could use to make them expand on hover, and remain collapsed when not hovered.

```
<section class="pt-5 pb-5 bg-color mt-4" id="services">
<div class="container pt-md-5 pb-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <p class="text-grey mb-1 l-head">What you Get</p>
      <h2 class="head2 pb-2">
        Our Services
      </h2>
      <div class="line mx-auto d-block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row pt-4">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-md-4 mt-2">
      <div class="services-item">
        <div class="services-sub">
          <a href=""><img src="assets/images/r1.jpg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Unique Orders, Unique Adventures</h4>
          <p>Your vision, our creation. Explore Cherrybery Studios' unique order service, where you can request
            custom mods tailored to your preferences. Elevate your gaming experience with personalized addons and
            plugins.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-md-4 mt-2">
      <div class="services-item">
        <div class="services-sub">
          <a href=""><img src="assets/images/r2.jpg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Gaming Beyond Boundaries</h4>
          <p>Join the adventure with Cherrybery Studios' game servers. Immerse yourself in a world where passion
            meets innovation. Explore unique gameplay experiences hosted on our servers and redefine your gaming
            journey.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-md-4 mt-2">
      <div class="services-item">
        <div class="services-sub">
          <a href=""><img src="assets/images/r3.jpg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Crafting Your Perfect Experience</h4>
          <p>Embark on unparalleled gaming adventures with Cherrybery Studios' meticulously crafted mods, plugins,
            and addons, introducing innovative features and seamless integrations to elevate and enrich your
            favorite games.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-md-4 mt-2">
      <div class="services-item">
        <div class="services-sub">
          <a href=""><img src="assets/images/r1.jpg" alt="img" class="img-fluid"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Curated Theme Packs</h4>
          <p>Dive into themed gaming with Cherrybery Studios' curated theme packs. Experience a fusion of mods,
            plugins, textures packs, integrations, and addons designed around many different specific themes or
            genres!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you're looking for (see interactive snippet below)?**

Using the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners, the blue div expands when hovered over, and returns to its original size when the mouse leaves its bounds.  The rate at which the div expands or contracts is proportional to the distance remaining before it reaches its maximum or minimum height. This gives a "snappier" looking animation than if the height were to change at a constant rate.

It should be pretty straightforward to customize this, like tweaking the expand/contract rate, adjusting the min/max height of the div (remember to change the starting value in the `style` element as well as the values in the script!), or extending the functionality to multiple boxes using `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`.

```js
var expandingBox = document.getElementById("expanding");
var boxHeight = {min: 60, max: 250, current: 60};
        
// Return a value which does not exceed the specified bounds (this is modeled on the p5.js constrain() function)
function constrainedValue(val, minV, maxV) {
    return (val < minV) ? minV : ((val > maxV) ? maxV : val);
}
        
function expand() {
    if (boxHeight.current < boxHeight.max) {
        expandVelocity = Math.max(0.1*(boxHeight.max - boxHeight.current), 1);
        boxHeight.current = constrainedValue(boxHeight.current + expandVelocity, boxHeight.min, boxHeight.max);
        expandingBox.style.height = boxHeight.current + "px";
        boxHeight.expandTimer = setTimeout(expand, 10);
    }
}
        
function contract() {
    if (boxHeight.current > boxHeight.min) {
        contractVelocity = Math.max(0.1*(boxHeight.current - boxHeight.min), 1);
        boxHeight.current = constrainedValue(boxHeight.current - contractVelocity, boxHeight.min, boxHeight.max);
        expandingBox.style.height = boxHeight.current + "px";
        boxHeight.contractTimer = setTimeout(contract, 10);
    }
}
        
expandingBox.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { if (boxHeight.contractTimer !== undefined) { clearTimeout(boxHeight.contractTimer); boxHeight.contractTimer = undefined; } expand(); });
expandingBox.addEventListener("mouseout", function() { if (boxHeight.expandTimer !== undefined) { clearTimeout(boxHeight.expandTimer); boxHeight.expandTimer = undefined; } contract(); });
```

```css
#expanding {
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p> Hover over the blue box to expand it.  The box will return to its original size when the mouse is removed. </p>
    <div id="expanding">
        <p>
            A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.<br><br>
            Peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.<br><br>
            She sells seashells by the seashore.<br><br>
            You'll be able to see this line once the box has expanded.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```